# Discord.py "ctx is a required argument that is missing."

Tags: python, command, bots, discord.py, ctx

I want my bot to reply with `hi` to `|hello`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "|")
bot.remove_command('help')

#just some console feedback thing, this works fine, dont think it matters here
@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(game=Game(name="The Gaming"))
    print('All systems online!')
    print('Bot name: '+ bot.user.name)
    servers = list(bot.servers)
    print("Connected to " + str(len(bot.servers)) + " servers")
    for x in range(len(servers)):
        print(' - ' + servers[x-1].name)

#the thing that actually refuses to work
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hi')

bot.run('████████████████████████████████████████████')
```

Instead of replying with `hi` to `|hello`, the bot displays the following error message in the console when `|hello` is sent:

```
Ignoring exception in command hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in invoke
    yield from self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 345, in prepare
    yield from self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 304, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = yield from self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 212, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

I have checked all dependencies, everything seems to be installed, hell this exact code worked flawlessly about a month ago.

I saw multiple other questions about this error, but all of them were using more complicated code that I'm just not experienced enough to understand.

How could I make it actually do it's thing?

Comment: Your code seems normal, is this all of your code?

Comment: Ensure your discord.py is up to date, at least 1.4.2

Comment: I suspect you are using a very old version of discord.py.  `bot.servers` should result in an error on discord.py>=1.0

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the command. Also, `bot.servers` doesnt exist, its `bot.guilds`.

```py
@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="The Gaming"))
    print('All systems online!')
    print('Bot name: '+ bot.user.name)
    servers = list(bot.guilds)
    print("Connected to " + str(len(bot.guilds)) + " servers")
    for x in range(len(servers)):
        print(' - ' + servers[x-1].name)

#There's nothing wrong with this command
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hi')
```

I didnt find any errors with the hello command. Im guessing that you are using an old version of discord.py . So you should switch to discord.py rewrite

Comment: it just
```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\DesktopFolders\bots\computer\computer.py", line 10, in on_ready
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="The Gaming"))
TypeError: change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activity'```
me, tried redownloading discord.py 2 times by now, both times it says `Requirement already satisfied...`

Comment: Have you tried using this

```pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]```